# Cannot read property 'aoColumns' of null

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using jquery datatables and the follow is the code that i'm using

```
function fnFixedColumnsTableTools() {
        var oTable = $(".datatable").dataTable({
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "bSort": false,
                "aaSorting": [],
                "iDisplayLength": -1,
                "sScrollX": "100%",
                "sScrollXInner": "150%",
                "bScrollCollapse": true,
                "oLanguage": { "sUrl": "Scripts/jquery.dataTables-ES.txt" },
                "sDom": '<"H"Tf>t<"F"i>',
                "oTableTools": {
                    "sRowSelect": "multi",
                    "sSwfPath": "Scripts/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                    "aButtons": [{ "sExtends": "copy", "bSelectedOnly": "true" }, "xls", "csv", "pdf"]
                }
        });
        new FixedColumns( oTable, {
            "iLeftColumns": 3,
            "iLeftWidth": 350
        } );
```

and this is a table that i use  in the datatable. this table is dinamic and create the columns number  in the side server

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvReport" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True" EnableViewState="False" CssClass="display dataTable" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No.">
                    <ItemTemplate><%#Container.DataItemIndex + 1%></ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: looks like dataTable is missing an attribute. (possibly it's name is even 'aoColumns'). make sure you supply all needed info.

Comment: already tried put the property aoColumns:null and continues appearing  the same mistake

Comment: make sure you supply all needed info.

Comment: and this is the code of side sever
 gvReport.DataSource =MobileReportsManager.GetReportsForms(Ddl_Forms.Text, dStart, dEnd, dcDrivers))

        gvReport.DataBind()